# Generating PDF with Puppeteer and display/save in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, puppeteer

I've been looking at options for generating a PDF from HTML, specifically in this case for use by an MVC (non-core) app.

I've looked at pdfSharp and have had success getting a byte array back, and returning a FileContentResult from my action. But I'm not keen on this route as it means manually created each PDF document with code.

Having stumbled upon Puppeteer, it seems like a good generic option to have a Node server with an endpoint I can call and pass some HTML, and it will render it as a PDF.

But I'm at a bit of a loss how to connect up everything.  Ideally, what I'd like is to call out to a node endpoint in my action method, get the PDF content back, then decide what to do with it, in my C# action method.

Does this make sense or is there a better approach?  I'm thinking Node+Express to give me an endpoint, but I'm not sure if the endpoint gives me back some kind of stream, how C# would recognize this (or if it would even need to, just plonk the content into a memorystream and carry on?)

Comment: Did you try Puppeteer-Sharp https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp ?

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at that.  Seems a bit overkill.  I actually got it working as per my aforementioned approach, it was literally a case of taking the result of the API call, as a byte[] and outputting it using "return File(...)".  

What i've actually done is added some code to Get the HTML from a View (that is, render the View and return the HTML) then I'm firing that HTML to the Node server.